# Deny from all не работает

Tags: .htaccess

Не могу понять, почему не работает. Закидываю в каталог с файлами .htaccess, но все ровно могу обратиться к файлам по прямой ссылке.

Проверяю на форматах: **png, jpg, doc, rar, zip, pdf**

Только **doc и pdf** **не скачивает**, не открывает и выдает 403 ошибку. Все остальное открывает и отдает на скачку.

Перепробовал уже все, но результат один и тот же. Как запретить?

Comment: покажите что ли свой htaccess...

Comment: Так в нем только: order allow,deny
deny from all

Comment: ссылка на него: https://yadi.sk/d/hFyxW9Fq3UaCok

Comment: Вот ссылка на pdf - он не открывается (http://img.moy-dogovor.ru/files/test/100002_1523101351.pdf )

Comment: ссылка на картинку - http://img.moy-dogovor.ru/files/test/100002_1523101312.jpg

Comment: картинку и проч. файлы, открываем спокойно.